# Chanuka Shavuos connection

Tags: chanuka, shavuos

What connections does Chanuka have with Shavuos?

Comment: Does someone say that there is a connection?

Comment: Is this a riddle?

Comment: On both holidays, shuls sponsor events during which people stay up very late eating food.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a riddle.

Answer (score 8):

There's a custom to eat dairy on each.

Answer (score 7):

Looking at book: Divine Design by Moshe Shlomo Emanuel ([here](http://books.google.com/books?id=SRT0EYUgnHcC&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=chanuka+shavuos+connection&source=bl&ots=o_ch0rV0AM&sig=iWnoRUEFQtshIxDriTxxrXQ9gXU&hl=en&ei=PBy9TJ6YEsH_lgez7dX9BA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false--)).

He lists various connections (summarized here):

- Chanukah celebrates the light of the Oral Torah, and Shavuos is when we received the written Torah
- They both connect to the number 8: Chanuka has 8 days, and Shavuos is the eight week after Pesach
- See source for more...

Answer (score 2):

The connetions between Chanuka and Shavuos include those answered, which in summary are:

A: Eating dairy on both.

B: Both celebrate the Torah.

C: Both connect to the number 8.

In addition to the above there are also the following connections.

A: Both Chanuka and Shavuos can technically come out on different days of the month. Shavuos is 50 days after Pesach. Although in the current calendar it always comes out on 6 Sivan, in the times of Kiddush HaChodesh it could come out as early as 5 Sivan and as late as 7 Sivan. (That is why we say "Zeman" Matan Toroseinu - instead of "Yom" Matan Toroseinu). Chanuka can end on either 2 Teves or 3 Teves.

B: According to the Shulchan Aruch Siman 428 the day of the week Chanuka starts is the same day Shavuos will start. The Mishna Berura says that it is an error and it is reversed to the day of the week Shavuos starts that will be the same day of the week the following Chanuka will start. However the Mishna Berura mentions that it only works if Cheshvan is 29 days, however if Cheshvan is 30 days then Chanuka will come out one day later in the week than Shavuos.

Comment: We don't say Yom Cheruteinu or Yom Simchateinu either though.

Comment: @Gershon-Gold "Kiddush HaChodesh it could come out as early as 5 Sivan and as late as 7 Sivan." What/When is "Kiddush HaChodesh"? Did the calendars back then have different days? Why if the count started on the 2nd day of Pesach would some declare 5 Sivan, and others 6 Sivan, and others still 7 Sivan as Shavuos?