# How long does a vow made "until it will be Shavuos" last?

Tags: nedarim-shevuot, shavuos

The mishnah in [Nedarim 8:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Nedarim.8.3?lang=bi) gives the following general rule:

> This is the rule: Anything that has a set time and he says, "until it
> reaches that time," he is forbidden until that time. If he says,
> "until it will be," he is forbidden until it passes. And anything that
> does not have a set time, whether he says "until it will be" or
> whether he says "until it reaches," he is only forbidden until it
> arrives.
>
> זֶה הַכְּלָל, כֹּל שֶׁזְּמַנּוֹ קָבוּעַ וְאָמַר *עַד שֶׁיַּגִּיעַ*, אָסוּר עַד שֶׁיַּגִּיּעַ. אָמַר *עַד שֶׁיְּהֵא*, אָסוּר עַד שֶׁיֵּצֵא. וְכֹל שֶׁאֵין זְמַנּוֹ קָבוּעַ, בֵּין אָמַר עַד שֶׁיְּהֵא, בֵּין אָמַר עַד שֶׁיַּגִּיעַ, אֵינוֹ אָסוּר אֶלָּא עַד שֶׁיַּגִּיעַ:‏

Shavuos doesn't have a fixed date, both because "[in the times of Kiddush HaChodesh it could come out as early as 5 Sivan and as late as 7 Sivan](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3603/13663)," and because depending on factors such as crossing the date line, one person's Shavuos can be on a different day as someone else's (don't have a source, it's just what my rabbi has said).

How does this work in the context of a neder?  Is Shavuos considered a "set time" for this purpose?

Comment: By Nedarim we follow common parlance. Commonly I'd think Shavout is assumed to have a fixed date.

Comment: @Double-AA Maybe people who live near the [date line](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/322/halakhic-international-date-line-issues) would be accustomed to thinking of Shavuos as not having a fixed date.

Comment: Nearly no one actually holds that crossing the dateline matters in this regard, so if you're looking for a common parlance you're unlikely to find a community that has one.

Comment: Is the calendar tag really appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

Shavuos has a set time even "in the times of Kiddush HaChodesh". It's *day 50 of the Omer"*!

So saying *until the 4th day of Pessach* or *until the 50th day of the Omer* (a.k.a Shavuos) would have the same status, i.e. something having a set time.

That's beside for [Double AA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa)'s comment (which is the *real* answer):
`By Nedarim we follow common parlance. Commonly I'd think Shavout is assumed to have a fixed date.`

<sup>Your comment about the Dateline is a total enigma to me.</sup>

Comment: The 8th day of Chanukka too is a good example

Comment: why don't you tick your own answer?

Comment: @user15464 - only the user who asked the question can "Tick" it.